# Jmeter 'View Results In Table' logging only partial requests

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I am running a test on Jmeter (Version 4.0) using Throughput Shaping Timer in order to achieve constant rate of hits per second.
I am logging all the data of 'view Results in table' to a file and using it to track all the requests.

The functionality of my application is such that When jmeter hits API , it creates a database entry for each of the hit.

After test execution is finished, I can see that number of results in log of 'View Results in Table' is less than the number of database entries created by jmeter test run. Also, I am able to arrive at the requests which are not present in logs, but are present in database.

Does 'View Results in Table' not save all the requests ?  How can this be changes to obtain data of all the requests ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [View Results Tree listener documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree):

> Starting with version 3.2 the number of entries in the View is restricted to the value of the property `view.results.tree.max_results` which defaults to `500` entries. The old behaviour can be restored by setting the property to `0`. Beware, that this might consume a lot of memory.

You can disable the limitation by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
view.results.tree.max_results=0
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

---

Be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1) (or whatever is the latest version at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible

Comment: I am aware of 500 entries in 'view results in tree' , but I am talking about 'view results in table'